# Is it possible to create custom java comparator which will compare by two different object properties?

Tags: java, comparator

Could you please help me to figure out how to implement comparator which will have the following algorithm?

Let's imagine we have class Order which have properties CollectionDT and OrderingDT.

What it's needed to sort list with Order objects by CollectionDT descending and if CollectionDT is null for some object passed to comparator then sort by OrderingDT.

The example and required output:

```
Order1: CollectionDT - 2022-08-17, OrderingDT - 2022-08-17 
Order2: CollectionDT - null, OrderingDT - 2022-08-18
Order3: CollectionDT - 2022-08-19, OrderingDT 2022-08-19
```

Needed output:

```
Order3
Order2
Order1
```

Comment: Post what you have so far - it should be a simple condition in the comparator to use a "getDt()" which returns "cdt" if not null OR returns "odt".  Then do the comparison on the result of "getDt()".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) has all you want. It could be something like this, though I doubt the correctness.

```
List<Order> orders = ...
orders.sort(Comparator.nullsFirst(Order::getCollectionDT)
                      .reversed()
                      .thenComparing(Order::getOrderingDT));
```

This would do CollectionDT sorted descendingly, the nulls at the end (nullsFirst+reversed), and equal CollectionDTs sorted by OrderingDT.

They must implement `Comparable<CollectionDT>` resp. `Comparable<OrderingDT>`.

It looks like you want something intertwined.
Then using a simple basic Comparator on compareTo.
More readable.

```
Comparator<Order> orderComparator = (lhs, rhs) ->
    lhs.getCollectionDT() == null
        ? rhs.getCollectionDT() != null ? 1
        : lhs.getOrderingDT().compareTo(rhs.getOrderingDT())
        : rhs.getCollection() == null ? -1
        : lhs.getCollectionDT().compareTo(rhs.getCollectionDT());
 orders.sort(orderComparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the time to code a demonstration of an answer in Eiffel for anyone who would like to see. You can find that video [here](https://youtu.be/l302rSA1eNs). You can look at the code directly from [Github](https://github.com/ljr1981/stack_overflow_answers/blob/main/src/so_73421489/so_73421489_order.e).

The primary goal of the demo is to show that objects in Eiffel can be taught how to compare themselves among themselves—such that—when you place them into a list, they auto-sort themselves by the code-rules you provide. This means you can also have descendant child classes that know how to sort themselves along with more generic parents in the same list, so you don't have to create lists of just one type of object.

You can even teach different objects that are otherwise unrelated how to organize themselves in the list, as long as they have some kind of loose inheritance. The Eiffel way of doing this is quite powerful!

I invite you to watch the video, examine the code on Github, download EiffelStudio (free GPL version) and play with the code directly! If you need help, reach out to me. I am happy to assist you in any way I can!

Comment: 1. it makes little sense to provide an Eiffel answer to a Java question 2. a good answer should be reasonably self-contained, not just reference external resources

Comment: It makes a great deal of sense to provide software engineers with information so that they know they have other choices. At a minimum, programmers ought to be able to see other choices and technologies so they can demand reciprocal choices in their own chosen tools—like Java.

Comment: I am going to give you a great example. Java has no built-in technology like Eiffel's Design-by-Contract. Most Java programmers are utterly unaware that such a thing exists. If they do know about DbC, the Java implementations of it are after-thoughts and Frankensteinish "bolt-on's". The treatment of DbC in Eiffel is elegant and powerful for finding bugs. Read the notes of the code in the link. https://github.com/ljr1981/stack_overflow_answers/blob/main/src/apps/application.e

Comment: Interestingly enough, even the Comparable<T> in Java is nothing more than an interface rather than a class, itself, such as it is in Eiffel (e.g. COMPARABLE). This goes to pointing out another technology available in Eiffel and not in Java—Multiple Inheritance. Because Java does not have MI, both language developers and programmers have had to invent Frankenstein workarounds that cause more problems, more convoluted code, and are a general source of confusion and bugs. Again—the point for us to see is that there are alternatives. Java is not "pure".

Comment: While it certainly makes sense to enlighten the poor mortals suffering in the Valley of Poor Technologies with the gospel of The Other Technology Which Will Eventually Save The World, off topic StackOverflow answers like this are really not a good way to do so.